# Python VTK on M2 macbook air

Tags: python, macos, dependencies, vtk, pyvista

I am writing this code for simulation of earths magnetic field:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import magpylib as magpy
import pyvista as pv

ts = np.linspace(-8,8, 150)
t = np.linspace(-6,6, 150)
axis = np.c_[2*np.cos(ts*2*np.pi), 2*np.sin(ts*2*np.pi), ts]
aux = np.c_[2*np.cos(ts*2*np.pi), 2*np.sin(ts*2*np.pi), t]
def make_coil(pos, vertices):
    coil = magpy.current.Line(
    current = 100,
    vertices = vertices,
    position= pos,
    style_color="green",
    )
    return coil

theta = np.sqrt(2)/2
r = 4
coil1 = make_coil((0,0,0), axis)
coil2 = make_coil((r*1,0,0), aux)
coil3 = make_coil((r*theta,r*theta,0), aux)
coil4 = make_coil((0,1*r,0), aux)
coil5 = make_coil((-r*theta,r*theta,0), aux)
coil6 = make_coil((-r*1,0,0), aux)
coil7 = make_coil((-r*theta,-r*theta,0), aux)
coil8 = make_coil((0,-r*1,0), aux)
coil9 = make_coil((r*theta,-r*theta,0), aux)

coil = coil1 + coil2 + coil3 + coil4 + coil5 + coil6 + coil7 + coil8 + coil9 
coil.show()



grid = pv.UniformGrid(
    dimensions=(41, 41, 41),
    spacing=(2, 2, 2),
    origin=(-40, -40, -40),
)

# compute B-field and add as data to grid
grid["B"] = coil.getB(grid.points)
# compute field lines
seed = pv.Disc(inner=1, outer=5.2, r_res=3, c_res=12)
strl = grid.streamlines_from_source(
    seed,
    vectors='B',
    max_time=180,
    initial_step_length=0.01,
    integration_direction='both',
)

# create plotting scene
pl = pv.Plotter()

# add field lines and legend to scene
legend_args = {
    'title': 'B [mT]',
    'title_font_size': 20,
    'color': 'black',
    'position_y': 0.25,
    'vertical': True,
}

# draw coils
magpy.show(coil, color="orange", canvas=pl, backend='pyvista')

# add streamlines
pl.add_mesh(
    strl.tube(radius=.2),
    cmap="bwr",
    scalar_bar_args=legend_args,
)
# display scene
pl.camera.position=(160, 10, -10)
pl.set_background("white")
pl.show()
```

and I get this error message

```
danieltran@eduroam-193-157-168-102 OneDrive-UniversitetetiOslo % /usr/local/bin/python3 "/Users/danieltran/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-UniversitetetiOslo/H22/FYS1120/Comp Essay/d
ouble_solenoids.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyvista/_vtk.py", line 547, in <module>
    from vtk.vtkCommonKitPython import buffer_shared, vtkAbstractArray, vtkWeakReference
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'vtk'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/danieltran/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-UniversitetetiOslo/H22/FYS1120/Comp Essay/double_solenoids.py", line 4, in <module>
    import pyvista as pv
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyvista/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from pyvista.plotting import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyvista/plotting/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .charts import Chart2D, ChartMPL, ChartBox, ChartPie
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyvista/plotting/charts.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pyvista import _vtk
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyvista/_vtk.py", line 549, in <module>
    from vtk.vtkCommonCore import buffer_shared, vtkAbstractArray, vtkWeakReference
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'vtk'.
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is, how do I fix the message "No module named 'vtk'", so I can run my code. As it looks I get the Error message because of my module "pyvista". And I have pip installed pyvista and installed vtk using homebrew. But I still get the error message

Comment: might need python 3.10 - do you have both, and does running `python3.11 -c 'import vtk'` or `python3.10 -c 'import vtk'` work?

Comment: I am still new to programming, so I am sorry if I am asking dumb questions. I know that I have python 3.11 installed. When you ask me if "python3.11 -c 'import vtk'" is running, what do you mean about that?

Comment: ah, within the Terminal app (more pleasant terminal emulators are available, but this is easy to try)

Comment: I pasted 'python3.10 -c 'import vtk'' in my terminal, and it looks like my terminal are downloading something.  My terminal has just frozen and I can not do anything in it

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to post a question, not just code + error message.

Based off of your error message, this is what I would try:

Ensure VTK is installed. https://pypi.org/project/vtk/

Try a different Python version. 3.11 is fresh off the shelf and it looks like the VTK library was last updated prior to 3.11's release.

There are other things that you could try but this is likely the best starting point based on your post...

Comment: this isn't really an Answer, but a comment - you'll be able to comment when you have [50 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)! can you give more details about _how_ they would install VTK (they mention they installed it from homebrew, which seems reasonable) or verify that it was installed correctly and that they have a python module for accessing it, not just the library?

Comment: That info wasn't available when I first replied... hard to give feedback when there's nothing besides an error message.

Answer (score 1):

VTK currently does not have a supported python 3.11 compatible version published.  See files available for latest version 9.2.2 https://pypi.org/project/vtk/9.2.2/#files which has no 3.11 compatible files [as of today].  Some options are to build VTK yourself (may or may not be possible without fixes to support python 3.11) or use a different python version or wait until a new vtk release that is compatible with python 3.11.